# Query string in url with :

Tags: jquery, html, css

```
$("#menu a").each(function(index) {
    if($.trim(this.href) == window.location.href) {
        $('div', this).addClass("cc");
    }
});
```

This is work when go to

```
example.com/foo/foo/
```

When navigate to second page for example

`example.com/foo/foo/p:2`

This does not work. How to make that query.

Comment: You can employ several methods of string manipulation to determine url equality. But, the problem you're encountering is a symptom of a deeper problem with urls in general. If you're having a `<link rel="canonical" href="...">` in your page, it might solve the problem as it's the most accurate value to compare the `this.href` to. See https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/139066?hl=en

Comment: Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `.indexOf` function to compare URLs.

```
$("#menu a").each(function(index) {
    var currentURL = window.location.href;
    var aHref = $.trim(this.href);
    if(currentURL.indexOf(aHref) !== -1) {
        $('div', this).addClass("cc");
    }
});
```